# Integration test passes in local but fails in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, odbc, xunit

I have written a integration test to validate a Odbc connection string. the test act on opening connection to provided connection string. It passes in my local machine but fails in Azure DevOps pipeline.

```
[Fact]
public void ValidateProperty_ValidConnectionString_ReturnsEmptyResult()
{
    // Arrange
    var validator = new OdbcConnectionStringPropertyValueValidation();
    string validConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Anywhere 16}; Links=tcpip(Host = serverName.com, Port = 2638; DoBroadcast=None); ServerName = name; UID = user; PWD = pass";

    // Act
    var result = validator.Validate_ValidateProperty(validConnectionString);

    // Assert
    Assert.False(result.HasValue);
}
```

Validator class -

```
public class OdbcConnectionStringPropertyValueValidation
{
    public OptionalResult<Issue> Validate_ValidateProperty(string connectionString)
    {
        // Check the ODBC connection string.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
        {
            return OptionalResult<Issue>.CreateWithValue(
                Issue.Error("The ODBC Connection String must be specified."));
        }

        // Validate the connection string.

        using (var odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Test the connection string, and produce a warning if it fails.
            try
            {
                odbcConnection.Open();
                return OptionalResult<Issue>.CreateEmpty();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return OptionalResult<Issue>.CreateWithValue(Issue.Warning(
                    $"A connection attempt using the ODBC Connection String \"{connectionString}\" failed: {ex.Message}"));
            }
            finally
            {
                odbcConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The azure pipeline-

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests. Then publishes any NuGet package created during build to Artifacts.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

# Install NuGet and restore packages
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install NuGet'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=5.3.0' 
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'A-Team'
    includeNuGetOrg: true

# Build
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'

# Test
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.sln'

# Copy the NuGet package to the artifact staging directory
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Stage NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    Contents: '**/bin/**/*.nupkg'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

# Publish the artifact staging directory (with the NuGet package in it)
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish NuGet Packages For (Potential) Release'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop
```

The error log-

```
2023-09-06T10:37:50.4236912Z [xUnit.net 00:00:04.67]     Fs.Validation.Tests.Validators.PropertyValidations.OdbcConnectionStringPropertyValueValidationTests.ValidateProperty_ValidConnectionString_ReturnsEmptyResult [FAIL]
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5288377Z   Failed Fs.Validation.Tests.Validators.PropertyValidations.OdbcConnectionStringPropertyValueValidationTests.ValidateProperty_ValidConnectionString_ReturnsEmptyResult [2 ms]
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5289207Z   Error Message:
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5289605Z    Assert.Equal() Failure
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5295505Z   Stack Trace:
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5296053Z      at Fs.Validation.Tests.Validators.PropertyValidations.OdbcConnectionStringPropertyValueValidationTests.ValidateProperty_ValidConnectionString_ReturnsEmptyResult() in D:\a\1\s\solutions\Fs.Validation\Fs.Validation.Tests\Validators\PropertyValidations\OdbcConnectionStringPropertyValueValidationTests.cs:line 21
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5296863Z    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
2023-09-06T10:37:50.5297248Z    at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
2023-09-06T10:37:50.6051327Z Results File: D:\a\_temp\VssAdministrator_fv-az770-998_2023-09-06_10_37_49.trx
2023-09-06T10:37:50.6055282Z 
2023-09-06T10:37:50.6155714Z Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:   185, Skipped:     0, Total:   186, Duration: 999 ms - Fs.Validation.Tests.dll (net7.0)
```

The connection string is valid and the database is hosted in a server. What could be the reason behind this? I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: You may get a better answer if you could be more specific than simply saying "it fails". Fails with what exception? Any details/stacktrace in the Exception?

Comment: In addition to what @NPras mentioned, also include how your Azure DevOps pipeline is setup and which agent pool is it running on? add as much detail as you can.

Comment: I added as much details as I could although the error log seems not much helpful. Do you think it could be issue with firewall in azure?